# How to implement django framework nested relationships?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have tried the option as shown on django rest framework docs, but still it wont work properly.when implementing the nested relashionship I only get the primary key of the lesson, I want all the lesson dedails to apear.Meaning A student has many lessons and I want to allow for each student to show his lessons.
Thank you!!
My code:

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import date


class Student(models.Model):

   
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    information = models.TextField(blank=True)
    objects = models.Manager()  # default manager


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-first_name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name


class Lesson(models.Model):

 
    options = (
        ('paid', 'Paid'),
        ('not paid', 'Not Paid'),
    )
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lessons')
    paid = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, choices=options, default='not paid')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    task1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description1 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    task2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description2 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lesson_date = models.DateField(default=date.today, null=False)
    objects = models.Manager()  # default manager
   
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-lesson_date',)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s: %s %s %s' % (self.student, self.title, self.lesson_date, self.paid)
```

Serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers, fields
from private_models.models import Lesson, Student


class LessonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #student = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
        fields = ('id', 'student', 'title', 'lesson_date', 'paid',)

    # def get_student(self, obj):
    #     return obj.student.first_name


class LessonDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
        fields = ('id', 'student', 'title', 'task1', 'description1',
                  'task2', 'description2', 'lesson_date', 'paid',)


class StudentDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'information',)


class StuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        lessons = LessonSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'information', 'lessons')
```

Views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from private_models.models import Lesson, Student
from .serializers import LessonSerializer, LessonDetailSerializer, StudentDetailSerializer, StuSerializer
# Create your views here.


class LessonList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Lesson.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LessonSerializer


class StuDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentDetailSerializer


class StuList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StuSerializer


class LessonDetail(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Lesson.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LessonDetailSerializer
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import LessonList, StuDetail, LessonDetail, StuList

app_name = 'private_api'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/', LessonDetail.as_view(), name='detailcreate'),
    path('', LessonList.as_view(), name='listcreate'),
    path('students/<int:pk>/', StuDetail.as_view(), name='sdetailcreate'),
    path('students/', StuList.as_view(), name='slistcreate'),
]
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models


@admin.register(models.Lesson)
class LessonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'student', 'title', 'lesson_date',
                    'paid')
    readonly_fields = ('lesson_date',)


admin.site.register(models.Student)
```

output - Have only the code of the lesson and not it's details.

```
GET /api/students/
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "first_name": "Tim",
        "last_name": "ff",
        "information": "ff",
        "lessons": [
            14
        ]
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Lory",
        "last_name": "AAf",
        "information": "ff",
        "lessons": []
    }
]
HTML form
Raw data

First name
Last name
Information
LessonsTim: sf 2021-05-26 not paid
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
class StuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lessons = LessonDetailSerializer(many=True) #add this so the lesson objects get serialized
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        lessons = LessonSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'information', 'lessons')
```